# Cache Group Policies for AD Group

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, group-policy

I administrate number of Windows 7 machines frozen using Faronics Deep Freeze.

Because these machines are kept frozen they do not cache group policies. So every time a user logs in after a reboot the machine must re-download the group policy. The group policies are quite large so the group policy retrieval and application can take several minutes.

I can't reduce the size of the group policies (Not my decision). Almost all of the users belong to the same groups.

Is there a way to pre-cache a specific set of group policies locally so first login for new users is faster?

Comment: Simplest solution.  Depending on the size.  Unlock the machine, user logs in, then lock the machine again.  Additionally  you could in theory adjust Faronics to avoid this, I am sure its possible, if it wasn't it wouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2):

*This started as a comment for clarification, but I think it's a possible answer, unless you can produce a lot of new information that supports what you seem to think is happening.

To that:

What on earth do you have in GP that takes *minutes* to download to the clients?  What is it that you expect to cache exactly? :)

Group policies are tiny, they are (for the most part) basically just a list of registry entries, settings files, and scripts.  The main exception to this could be if you're doing software distribution via GP, but even then the GPOs themselves are just telling it what to install and where to install it from.

GP login slowness usually comes from what the GP's cause to happen, like drives being mapped, scripts running and doing things that take time, etc.

With a program like Deep Freeze involved, and the presumption that GP is applying fast on non-frozen machines, then it sounds more likely that the GP system is trying to write to something that's frozen (like the registry), and it's just sitting/retrying until it eventually times-out.

That time out could be just about anything, since it's settable by the admin in GP (I think by default it's about 30 seconds, but people often turn it up to make up for possible network speed limitations).

As you probably know, Deep Freeze Enterprise enables you to setup a regular maintenance Window, but this doesn't help much when GP is being applied at login, and by default re-applied every like 15 minutes or so.

So, how to deal with it? Prevent GP updates until you're ready to do them manually...

- Put all the frozen computers into their own OU(s) so they can be easily targeted by different GPOs.
- Unfreeze the computers and run `GPupdate /force /boot`.
- Reboot, and log in as the usual user to apply all GP settings.
- Check the event logs (etc.) to ensure all the GP's applied as expected.
- Freeze the machines again.
- On the OU(s) you put the clients in, right-click and enable the "Block inheritance" setting.

Next time you want to update them, turn off the "Block inheritance", unfreeze them, gpupdate, freeze, block inheritance again.

If you have specific GPOs that you have/want to always apply to the frozen computers (regardless of their frozen state), then link those GPOs directly to the OU(s) you created for the frozen machines.